# Nan behaves differently in #pragma cpp

Tags: c++, nan, pragma

I am learning about the `NaN` datatype, so, I ran a code to understand it and it goes well, the code worked as expected, but when I add a line `#pragma GCC optimize("Ofast")` in my code then, it behaves unexpected. I am curious why??

```
#pragma GCC optimize("Ofast")
// C++ code to check for NaN exception
// using "==" operator
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Driver Code
int main()
{
  float a = sqrt(2);
  float b = sqrt(-2);

  // Returns true, a is real number
  // prints "Its a real number"
  a == a ? cout << "Its a real number" << endl
    : cout << "Its NaN" << endl;

  // Returns false, b is complex number
  // prints "Its nan"
  b == b ? cout << "Its a real number" << endl
    : cout << "Its NaN" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The ouput without pragma is

```
Its a real number
Its NaN
```

But after using pragma it gives

```
Its a real number
Its a real number
```

Comment: -Ofast makes things fast while ignoring compliance with standards (like IEEE-754), so it isn't a surprise that NaN doesn't work properly with that optimization on, though it probably varies based on your version of gcc. Also, NaN isn't its own "data type", it is just a possible floating-point value (at least in IEEE-754 it is, some other floating-point number systems do not have the concept of NaN).

Comment: Note that `b` is not actually a complex number.  You would need to use a complex datatype, such as `std::complex<float>`, and call the complex-arithmetic version of `sqrt` to get a complex number.  What you have now is just `sqrt` giving up because the result is not a real, so it cannot be represented by the return datatype `float`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-Ofast turns on -ffast-math, which turns on -ffinite-math-only, which does the following (from the gcc documentation here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

> -ffinite-math-only
>
> Allow optimizations for floating-point arithmetic that assume that
> arguments and results are not NaNs or +-Infs.
>
> This option is not turned on by any -O option since it can result in
> incorrect output for programs that depend on an exact implementation
> of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions. It may,
> however, yield faster code for programs that do not require the
> guarantees of these specifications.

I think the "-O option" part is wrong since the -Ofast documentation says it "disregards strict standards compliance". That, or by "any -O option" they mean -O1, -O2, -O3.